# Invalid syntax error "type= MyISAM" in DDL generated by Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, mariadb

I am getting this error for my Java code

```
   Caused by :`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException`: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB` server version for the right syntax to use near 'type = `MyISAM`' at line 1
```

This is the query passed by hibernate:

```
Hibernate: create table EMPLOYEE (emp_id integer not null, FNAME varchar(255), LNAME varchar(255), primary key (emp_id)) type=MyISAM
```

I have looked at all questions related to this error. But in all that questions the user itself is passing query "`type = MyISAM`" so they can change "`type`" to "`engine`", but here hibernate is responsible for creating table, so I don't understand where the mistake is, and how I can fix it.

This is my configuration file:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory >
 <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/servletcheck</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password"> </property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
  <mapping resource="Employee.hbm.xml"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is my mapping file:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="first.Employee" table="EMPLOYEE">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="emp_id" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="fname" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="FNAME" />
        </property>
        <property name="lname" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="LNAME" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

This is my class file:

```
public class StoreData {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration cfg=new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        SessionFactory factory=cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session=factory.openSession();
        org.hibernate.Transaction t=session.beginTransaction();
        Employee e=new Employee();
        e.setId(1);
        e.setFname("yogesh");
        e.setLname("Meghnani");
        session.persist(e);
        t.commit();

    }
}
```

Comment: Please read question again...i had almost read all questions related to it..the one you linked also,but i didn't got any solution.In all that question they are passing sql query but here i am using hibernate to create table.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson This question is not a duplicate of the linked question, as the problem here is specifically DDL generated by a Hibernate-dialect, not a generic problem.

Comment: @ScaryWombat - It is _not_ an "exact duplicate".  The OP knows that `TYPE` is the problem, but the "duplicate" does not say how to solve it for `hibernate`.  So, I hereby un-duplicate-of this question.  And leave Mark's Accepted Answer as a good one.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

The problem is that - in Hibernate 5.x and earlier - the dialect `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect` is for MySQL 4.x or earlier. The fragment `TYPE=MYISAM` that is generated by this dialect was deprecated in MySQL 4.0 and removed in 5.5.

Given that you use MariaDB, you need to use (depending on the version of MariaDB and - maybe - the version of Hibernate) one of:

- `org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect`
- `org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB53Dialect`
- or higher versions (e.g. `org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB106Dialect`)

If you are using MySQL, or if the above two dialects for MariaDB don't exist in your version of Hibernate:

- `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect`
- `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect`
- `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect`
- `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect`
- or variants of these dialects (e.g. `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57InnoDBDialect`)

NOTE: With Hibernate 6, you should once again use `MySQLDialect` or `MariaDBDialect`, as Hibernate 6 dialects will configure themselves based on the actual connected version.

Comment: To me also worked with org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57InnoDBDialect (MySQL 8.x)

Comment: @Vikcen For MySQL 8, I suggest using `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect` instead

Comment: Yes... @Mark Rotteveel, but my current version of Hibernate core is 5.2.17 and it doesnt have MySQL8Dialect, but anyway i will change it for another because MySQL57InnoDBDialect is deprecated, just i noticed.

Comment: With Hibernate 6, all of the INNO dialects are gone and MySQL8Dialect is marked as deprecated - despite this, switching (as directed in the deprecation warning) to the MySqlDialect will cause the error from the OP!

Comment: @CharlesHasegawa As far as I'm aware, Hibernate 6 dialects should configure themselves based on the connected database version. If this doesn't work correctly, then it should be reported to Hibernate as a bug. And looking at the code in [hibernate/main](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQLDialect.java#L210), it should not produce the error from the OP, for two reasons, 1) it uses the `ENGINE` keyword instead of `TYPE`, and 2) it defaults to using innodb.

Comment: @CharlesHasegawa Maybe you're using an *older* MySQL version than 5.7, and should be using `org.hibernate.community.dialect.MySQLLegacyDialect`? Alternatively, you have a broken classpath, and it is picking up the MySQLDialect of a Hibernate 5 or older version.

Comment: For me org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect worked . I am using MySQL 8.1.0 version

Answer (score 28):

It's a Dialect related issue, instead of `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect` you can go with `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect`. It will work happily.

Answer (score 7):

This error may arise with increasing frequency as more organizations move to install MySQL 8.x while their Hibernate code is still using the old version 5 Dialect.

The latest Hibernate 5.4 distribution as of 6/6/2020 includes the following MySQL dialects:

- MySQL55Dialect
- MySQL57Dialect
- MySQL57InnoDBDialect
- MySQL5Dialect
- MySQL8Dialect
- MySQLDialect
- MySQLInnoDBDialect
- MySQLISAMDialect

**Current Hibernate 5.4 MySQL dialects**

Here's the dialects in the core jar file filtered for MySQL. Use the right one and that [type=MyISAM MySQL](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/How-to-fix-the-MySQL-typeMyISAM-SQLSyntaxErrorException-in-Hibernate-and-JPA) exception will be a thing of the past.

[image]

Comment: Hibernate 6 will contain less dialects. In Hibernate 6, a dialect will configure itself with connection metadata to enable or disable features.

Comment: Mind blown. I edited out the suggestion to look for new dialects when version 6 is released to reflect your insights.

Answer (score 2):

Before MySQL 4.x.x version,TYPE MYISAM engine is used to store tables but in MySQL 5.x.x or later version MySQL is used ENGINE = MYISAM to store tables.
e.g

In MySQL 4.x.x or < 4.x.x

```
CREATE TABLE t (i INT) TYPE = MYISAM;
```

In MySQL 5.x.x or > 5.x.x

```
CREATE TABLE t (i INT) ENGINE = MYISAM;
```

Now lets talk about hibernate,

In hibernate you must use given below dialect

MySQL <= 4.x.x

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
```

MySQL>=5.x.x.

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
```

It will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a old post but I am sharing a different experience. I was also seeing the same exact exception but i had MySQL 8 with Springboot+ JPA+ Hibernate .

My dialect looks like

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

But I was still seeing the issue. After some troubleshooting I noticed that the issue was in the schema sql where I had the table creation script in all Caps and it was expected to have it in small. For example

```
CREATE TABLE  item_catalog
```

instead of

```
CREATE TABLE  ITEM_CATALOG
```

After changing the case in the schema sql to lower case table name, It worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL dropped MyISAM as the default engine. Now it uses InnoDB. You can verify this using SequelPro by clicking on any table, and then looking in the bottom quadrant for the Table Information:

[image]

And at the top of your window to see the MySQL Version:

[image]

Using the above information, I know that I need the dialect:

`org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect`

I can set the dialect in my application.properties: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to find the available dialects, no matter which database you need a dialect that works on your system.

**> Project> Libraries> hibernate-core> org.hibernate.dialect**

Then you will see a **package** of several "dialect" classes for different databases and you can test one that works. This case is for **hibernate**.