# Spring Boot - “Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'” - Start

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have seen a lot of questions but the answers are not satisfying my problem...

I generate my project with Spring initialzr
[image]

I tried with the 3 java versions 14, 11, 8.

This is my project structure.

[image]

**GardenApplication.java**. I include all anottations even spring doc says that with @SpringBootApplication is enough. Before this error @Repository couldn't be found and I include @EnableJpaRepositories

```
package com.garden.garden;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({"com.garden.garden.controller", "com.garden.garden.service.impl"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.garden.garden.repository"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.garden.garden.model"})
public class GardenApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GardenApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**VegetableController.java**

```
package com.garden.garden.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.garden.garden.model.Vegetable;
import com.garden.garden.service.VegetableService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping
public class VegetableController {

    @Autowired
    private VegetableService vegetableService;

    @GetMapping("/vegetableList")
    public String list(Model model) {
        List<Vegetable> listVegetables = vegetableService.list();
        model.addAttribute("vegetables", listVegetables);
        return "index";
    }

}
```

**VegetableServiceImpl.java**

```
package com.garden.garden.service.impl;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.garden.garden.model.Vegetable;
import com.garden.garden.repository.VegetableRepository;
import com.garden.garden.service.VegetableService;

@Service
public class VegetableServiceImpl implements VegetableService {

    @Autowired
    private VegetableRepository vegetableRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Vegetable> list() {
        return (List<Vegetable>) vegetableRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Vegetable> listById(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int save(Vegetable vegetable) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

**VegetableService.java**

```
package com.garden.garden.service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import com.garden.garden.model.Vegetable;

public interface VegetableService {
    public List<Vegetable> list();
    public Optional<Vegetable> listById(int id);
    public int save(Vegetable vegetable);
    public void delete(int id);
}
```

**VegetableRepository.java**

```
package com.garden.garden.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.garden.garden.model.Vegetable;

@Repository
public interface VegetableRepository extends JpaRepository<Vegetable, Integer> {

}
```

**Vegetable.java**

```
package com.garden.garden.model;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "vegetable")
public class Vegetable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String family;
    private int daysOnNursery;
    private int daysToGrow;
    private int daysHarvesting;
    private java.math.BigDecimal plantsPerSquare;
    private java.math.BigDecimal price;
    private java.math.BigDecimal weight;



    public Vegetable(int id, String name, String family, int daysOnNursery, int daysToGrow, int daysHarvesting,
            BigDecimal plantsPerSquare, BigDecimal price, BigDecimal weight) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.family = family;
        this.daysOnNursery = daysOnNursery;
        this.daysToGrow = daysToGrow;
        this.daysHarvesting = daysHarvesting;
        this.plantsPerSquare = plantsPerSquare;
        this.price = price;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getFamily() {
        return family;
    }

    public void setFamily(String family) {
        this.family = family;
    }

    public int getDaysOnNursery() {
        return daysOnNursery;
    }

    public void setDaysOnNursery(int daysOnNursery) {
        this.daysOnNursery = daysOnNursery;
    }

    public int getDaysToGrow() {
        return daysToGrow;
    }

    public void setDaysToGrow(int daysToGrow) {
        this.daysToGrow = daysToGrow;
    }

    public int getDaysHarvesting() {
        return daysHarvesting;
    }

    public void setDaysHarvesting(int daysHarvesting) {
        this.daysHarvesting = daysHarvesting;
    }

    public java.math.BigDecimal getPlantsPerSquare() {
        return plantsPerSquare;
    }

    public void setPlantsPerSquare(java.math.BigDecimal plantsPerSquare) {
        this.plantsPerSquare = plantsPerSquare;
    }

    public java.math.BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(java.math.BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public java.math.BigDecimal getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(java.math.BigDecimal weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

}
```

I also try to solve the problem adding this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.garden</groupId>
    <artifactId>garden</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>garden</name>
    <description>Market garden web application</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>14</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/garden
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Comment: This usually happens when you don't have access to your database. Can you check that you can access your MySql database using what you provided in application.properties?

Comment: You are right. I don't include time zone in the connection url. At the beginning I solve this problem adding this property spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove the exclusion of the auto configuration in your `application.properties`  and add an hibernate-dialect, i.e. update your `application.properties` as follows:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/garden
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

In addition you can simplify `GardenApplication`  to

```
package com.garden.garden;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EntityScan
public class GardenApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(GardenApplication.class, args);
  }

}
```

and remove tomcat dependency from your pom (it comes in transitively with `spring-boot-starter-web`).
Besides, having lombok in your dependencies, you can annotate `Vegetable` with `@Data` and remove Getters, Setters and the constructor.

Comment: The spring.autoconfigure.exclude = org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration was the one that cause the problem. I add this because I read in other post that with that I solve the error of mysql server time zone.

Comment: Also I have to say that if I add spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect I get an error executing DDL type=MyISAM. Is no need to expecified this, I read in other post that if you add this property you have to especify mysql version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43716068/invalid-syntax-error-type-myisam-in-ddl-generated-by-hibernate