# Can't fix error in Beginner Hibernate Program

Tags: java, hibernate

I've just started learning Hibernate, and attempted the example at https://www.javatpoint.com/example-to-create-hibernate-application-in-eclipse-ide , with slight modifications. I received a huge error log -

```
Jun 13, 2020 7:59:26 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.1.Final}
Jun 13, 2020 7:59:26 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Jun 13, 2020 7:59:26 PM org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
Jun 13, 2020 7:59:27 PM org.hibernate.spatial.integration.SpatialService <init>
INFO: HHH80000001: hibernate-spatial integration enabled : true
Jun 13, 2020 7:59:27 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.3.Final}
Jun 13, 2020 7:59:27 PM org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
Jun 13, 2020 7:59:28 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Jun 13, 2020 7:59:28 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost/hibernatedb2]
Jun 13, 2020 7:59:28 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root}
Jun 13, 2020 7:59:28 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Jun 13, 2020 7:59:28 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Jun 13, 2020 7:59:28 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Jun 13, 2020 7:59:28 PM org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl configure
INFO: Envers integration enabled? : true
Jun 13, 2020 7:59:29 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@34cf5a97] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Jun 13, 2020 7:59:29 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table emp (id integer not null, firstName varchar(255), lastName varchar(255), primary key (id)) type=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table emp (id integer not null, firstName varchar(255), lastName varchar(255), primary key (id)) type=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:277)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467)
    at firsthb.FunctionalityImplementer.main(FunctionalityImplementer.java:18)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=MyISAM' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3933)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3869)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2524)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2675)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2465)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2439)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:829)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:729)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 11 more

Jun 13, 2020 7:59:29 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
Jun 13, 2020 7:59:29 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Table 'hibernatedb2.emp' doesn't exist
Jun 13, 2020 7:59:29 PM org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl mapManagedFlushFailure
ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement]
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1460)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:511)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3278)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2474)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:98)
    at firsthb.FunctionalityImplementer.main(FunctionalityImplementer.java:28)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3136)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3651)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:356)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1454)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'hibernatedb2.emp' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3933)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3869)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2524)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2675)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2465)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1912)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2133)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2067)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5175)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2052)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
    ... 17 more
```

This is my POJO class -

```
package firsthb;

public class Employee {

    private int id;
    private String firstName, lastName;

    //getters and setters
    public int getId() {    
        return id;  
    }

    public void setId(int id) { 
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {    
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {  
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

employee.hbm.xml (Hibernate mapping file) -

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 5.3//EN"  
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-5.3.dtd">

 <hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Employee" table="emp">
        <meta attribute="class-description">
        This class contains employees' details
        </meta>

        <id name="id">
        <generator class="assigned"></generator>
        </id>

        <property name="firstName"/>
        <property name="lastName"/>

    </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml (Hibernate Configuration file) -

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC  
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 5.3//EN"  
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-5.3.dtd">  


<hibernate-configuration>  

    <session-factory>  

        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>  
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>  
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>  
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/hibernatedb2</property>  
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>    
    <mapping resource="employee.hbm.xml"/>  
    </session-factory>  

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Finally, the class with the data manipulation functionality -

```
package firsthb;

import org.hibernate.Session;  
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;  
import org.hibernate.Transaction;  
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;  
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;  
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;  
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class FunctionalityImplementer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StandardServiceRegistry ssr = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();
        Metadata meta = new MetadataSources(ssr).getMetadataBuilder().build();

        SessionFactory factory = meta.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();

        Employee e1 = new Employee();
        e1.setId(1);
        e1.setFirstName("Elon");
        e1.setLastName("Musk");

        session.save(e1);
        t.commit();
        System.out.println("Successfully saved");
        factory.close();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

The mysql-connector-java-5.1.48-bin.jar file has been added to the classpath. So have all the other jars specified in the example I'm attempting.

Please let me know what the problem is.

Comment: Duplicate of [Invalid syntax error "type= MyISAM" in DDL generated by Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43716068/invalid-syntax-error-type-myisam-in-ddl-generated-by-hibernate)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turned out the solution was there on StackOverflow, albeit under a different heading:
[Invalid syntax error "type= MyISAM" in DDL generated by Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43716068/invalid-syntax-error-type-myisam-in-ddl-generated-by-hibernate)

Long story short, change the dialect in hibernate.cfg.xml to `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect` and things will run fine.