# hibernate hbm2ddl.auto creates strange SQL query

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate ( version "5.4.24.Final" ) and when applying its property "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" there is a strange SQL query executed:

```sql
drop table if exists Student;
create table Student (id integer not null, colour varchar(255), name varchar(255), primary key (id)) type=MyISAM
```

and the type=MyISAM is not recognised by SQL server which shows this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=MyISAM' at line 1.

Could anyone give me an help?

Comment: Please only tag the RDBMS you are *actually* using.  The error clearly states you are using MySQL, so I have removed [tag:sql-server].

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL it is `ENGINE` not type

```
drop table if exists Student;
 create table Student (id integer not null, colour varchar(255), name varchar(255), primary key (id)) ENGINE =MyISAM
```

You are using the wrong dialect as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43716068/invalid-syntax-error-type-myisam-in-ddl-generated-by-hibernate)

Comment: I have no control to the query, it's automatically generated by hibernate framework. Thank you for advice anyways

Comment: Soory i forgot to mention https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43716068/invalid-syntax-error-type-myisam-in-ddl-generated-by-hibernate