# MySQL table not create . Why this error come in run spring boot project?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

im creating a customer table using java. but when I'm run project console said like this.

> Hibernate: create table customer (id bigint not null auto_increment, dob date, full_name varchar(255), installment integer, loan_amount float, email_id varchar(255), primary key (id)) type=MyISAM
> 2023-02-16 11:07:21.855  WARN 7288 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table customer (id bigint not null auto_increment, dob date, full_name varchar(255), installment integer, loan_amount float, email_id varchar(255), primary key (id)) type=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement

How do I fix this error?

Comment: seeing as you don't tell us what the error is, don't know

Comment: Did you check this answer?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43716068/invalid-syntax-error-type-myisam-in-ddl-generated-by-hibernate

Comment: type=MyISAM -  I don't see type = as a table option https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html perhaps engine =

Comment: You probably need to specify a different dialect, recent MySQL versions don't support `type=MyISAM`.